# Could Anyone explain about this code?

Tags: scala, recommendation-engine

according this link: https://github.com/amplab/training/blob/ampcamp6/machine-learning/scala/solution/MovieLensALS.scala

I don't understand what is the point of :

```
val numUsers = ratings.map(_._2.user).distinct.count
val numMovies = ratings.map(_._2.product).distinct.count
```

`_._2.[user|product]` , what does that mean?

Comment: `ratings` contains tuple of `N` elements. `_._2` means "access the tuple in the place of the second element". `_` is a placeholder for the entire tuple, it's equivalent to `.map(x => x._2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is accessing the tuple elements: The following example might explain it better.

```
val xs = List(
  (1, "Foo"), 
  (2, "Bar")
)

xs.map(_._1) // => List(1,2) 
xs.map(_._2) // => List("Foo", "Bar")

// An equivalent way to write this
xs.map(e => e._1)
xs.map(e => e._2)

// Perhaps a better way is
xs.collect {case (a, b) => a} // => List(1,2)
xs.collect {case (a, b) => b} // => List("Foo", "Bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

ratings is a collection of tuples:(timestamp % 10, Rating(userId, movieId, rating)). The first underscore in _._2.user refers to the current element being processed by the map function. So the first underscore now refers to a tuple (pair of values). For a pair tuple t you can refer to its first and second elements in the shorthand notation: t._1 & t._2  So _._2 is selecting the second element of the tuple currently being processed by the map function.

```
val ratings = sc.textFile(movieLensHomeDir + "/ratings.dat").map { line =>
  val fields = line.split("::")
  // format: (timestamp % 10, Rating(userId, movieId, rating))
  (fields(3).toLong % 10, Rating(fields(0).toInt, fields(1).toInt, fields(2).toDouble))
}
```